# Proj4 - TypeError: lib_namespaceObject is not a function

Tags: typescript, proj

I'm trying to convert some coordinates with proj4, but I get this error

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: lib_namespaceObject is not a function`

proj4 is called from inside a typescript module.
proj4 version: 2.6.3

My code:

```
import * as proj4 from 'proj4'
import * as atlas from 'azure-maps-control';

//...

fetch('...')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data: atlas.data.FeatureCollection) => {
     data.features = data.features.filter(f => f.geometry);
     data.features.forEach(f => {
       let from = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
       let to = "+title=WGS 84 (long/lat) +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees";

       f.geometry.coordinates[0] = proj4(from, to, f.geometry.coordinates[0] as any);
       f.geometry.coordinates[1] = proj4(from, to, f.geometry.coordinates[1] as any);
     });
  });
```

The error appears on row:

`f.geometry.coordinates[0] = proj4(from, to, f.geometry.coordinates[0] as any)`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now. Had to change the import to

```
import proj4 from 'proj4'
```